# What are the things that Law of cricket permits but ICC Outlawed?

Tags: rules, cricket, icc

For example, there is a set of rules in [laws of cricket](http://www.rulesofcricket.co.uk/the_rules_of_cricket/the_rules_of_cricket_law_2.htm) for using By-runners for batsmen. But, later [Icc disallowed](http://www.bbc.com/sport/0/cricket/15135524) the runners from international matches.

Like this, is there any other things that Icc outlawed the laws of cricket in international matches?

If you know just one, you can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- One rule that comes to my mind is the 'Declaration Rule' for Limited Overs Internationals.

While the Laws of Cricket state that you can declare an innings in a match of any length(ie Test or ODI or T20), ICC prohibits it. All international matches are played in accordance respective 'ICC Playing Conditions' rulebook.
You can check out the Playing Conditions Books [here](http://www.icc-cricket.com/about/38/rules-and-regulations)

A brief list :
**ICC Test Matches**

- Law 5.6 of the Laws of Cricket which makes specification about the ball does not apply to ICC Test matches.
- Playing on non-turf pitches (according to Law 7.5) is not allowed.
- Law 12.1(b) (as below, ) is not permitted in Test matches.

> It may be agreed to limit any innings to a number of overs or to a
>   period of time.

- Single inning test matches (according to Law 21.2) are not allowed.

**ICC ODIs**

- All the rules related to test matches(ie, Follow-ons, adding time between innings, adding time at the end of the day, changing the ball after one day's play, etc) are all obviously not applicable.
- Declaration of innings, according to Law 14, is not permitted
- According to Law 1.1

> By agreement a match may be played between sides of fewer than, or
>   more than, eleven players, but not more than eleven players may field
>   at any time.

This is not applicable to ODIs played between ICC Members and/or ICC Affliates